# Uninstall current gcc version and install old version

Tags: c, gcc

I currently have gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010. For some reason I have to install gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313. How Can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

gcc versions can coexists, you don't need to uninstall the system one.

<s>try `apt-get install gcc-4.7`</s>

After installing you'll need to change your makefile or your env to point to the proper tool chain instead of default gcc

Answer (score 0):

You should visit https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-4.4/ to search for the version you want.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/mirrors.html 
has a list of mirrors where you can download the source files for whichever version you want. You can then easily build it yourself.

Note that the version you need is GCC 4.4.7 and NOT GCC 4.7.